# My If statement doesnt seem to be working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to verify that a tag/data value exists before proceeding and keep getting index error

This is my one line that is not working
    if len(data['descriptive'][0]['partNumber']) > 0:

## Below is the latest logic im trying to make work

```
    jvscript = soup.select_one('#skuDescriptivattribute').text
    prdDts = soup.find_all('div',class_="product-details") 

    if len(jvscript) > 0:
        data = jvscript
        data = json.loads(data)
        if len(data['descriptive'][0]['partNumber']) > 0:
            dets['sku'] = data['descriptive'][0]['partNumber']
        else:
            print("SKU NOT FOUND")
    elif len(prdDts) > 0:
        print("Out Of Stock")
    else:
        print("No Sku Available")
```

What i want to check is if that "partnumber" tag/value exists. If it does then grab it, if not then a simple canned message will be populated

**Error in the console when running:**

```
if len(data['descriptive'][0]['partNumber']) > 0:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

**If i try the other suggestion below i get this error:**

```
if 'partNumber' in data['descriptive'][0]:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Now im getting this error after the suggestions and trying it against the list again**

```
jvscript = soup.select_one('#skuDescriptivattribute').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Basically i want to check if the tags or data exists on the page before proceeding.  I ran my spider against 2655 urls.. and once i opened the resulting file, i found that most of the records that had my generic messages like above, didnt exist to begin with and for other reason, so thats the reason im trying to add the above logic so i can validate what tags exists, so i know how to populate my list of values and save it accordingly.. i rather provide the user a useful message then just a generic place holder of "Sku goes here"

Comment: Can you please show us what 'data' looks like?

Comment: When you say "it's not working", what do you mean? It throws an error? Doesn't trigger? Gives wrong output? _Which_ `if` block doesn't work? And please check your indentation, this code will throw an error

Comment: Fix your indentation below `if len(jvscript) > 0:`

Comment: if it is an index problem than it is not an "if" problem, check your dataset, and if it throws an error please provide it with the question

Comment: Here is the error i see in the console         if len(data['descriptive'][0]['partNumber']) > 0:

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

you can check if 'partNumber' is in the dictionary like so:

```
if 'partNumber' in data['descriptive'][0]:
    ...
```

EDIT removed unnecessary .keys